# Call Anonymous binded delegate method of radiobutton CheckedChanged

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, event-handling, anonymous-methods

I have a dynamically generated radio button with anonymous delegate declared as

in

```
private void SetFieldDependency(DocumentSimpleFieldDetailDto obj, Table table, RadioButton ctrlExtended, Panel pnl)
    {
        if (this.ListOfDependentFields != null)
        {
            var lstRelatedField = this.TemplateCompiledDto.LstSimpleFields.Where(a => a.FkDocumentTemplateSectionId == obj.FkDocumentTemplateSectionId
                                                                                && !a.IsGridField && a.FieldGroup == obj.FieldGroup);
            var objDependencyList = this.ListOfDependentFields.FindAll(h => lstRelatedField.Any(k => h.ParentFieldId == k.TemplateSimpleFieldDetailId));
            if (objDependencyList != null && objDependencyList.Count > 0)
            {
                ctrlExtended.AutoPostBack = true;
                ctrlExtended.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>
                                                   {
                                                       foreach (var fieldDependency in objDependencyList.Where(h => h.ChildFieldId != null))
                                                       {
                                                           var tr = table.FindControl(fieldDependency.ChildFieldId.ToString()) as TableRow;
                                                           if (tr != null)
                                                           {
                                                               if (fieldDependency.ParentFieldId == obj.TemplateSimpleFieldDetailId)
                                                               {
                                                                   tr.Visible = true;
                                                               }
                                                               else
                                                               {
                                                                   tr.Visible = !tr.Visible;
                                                               }                                                                   
                                                           }
                                                       }
                                                       SetGridFieldDependency(obj, pnl, objDependencyList);
                                                   };
            }
        }
    }
```

Now on some button submit event I have to call this `radiobutton` `CheckChanged` Event.If it is like `ctrlExtended_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e)`

I can easily call but how can i call binded anonymous delegate method?

Also I am using Asp.net

Comment: Technically you could, but seems a bit backward and long-winded, why not just define the thing proper?

Comment: have edited my question a bit.Hope it will clear my question more

Answer (score 1):

if some other event need to triger this event `CheckedChanged` then you should definetly call `CheckedChanged` event. if you just want the logic in the anonymous delegate method to be called i suggest you place that logic in a method and call that method

**edit**

```
ctrlExtended.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>{
  // My logic
  SharedLogic(sender, e);
}
.
.
.
public void SharedLogic(object sender, EventHandler e)
{
// the shared logic
}
```

in that way when the event `CheckedChanged` fired your logic will still be called upon, but also the method SharedLogic will be called, and you can call that method from elsewhere

Comment: when people downvote you and don't leave a comment it suggest reputation hunter

Comment: I think you might haven't understand the question. The thing you mentioned

Comment: let's see: you have an anonymous delegate method and you want to call it from a different location then just the event, am i close?

Comment: yeah exactly i just elaborated you answer more that it mate...you were right in the first place...:)

Comment: I swear Shaz and "No Idea for Name" that i didn't downvote any of your answer dears

Comment: in that case iam soory mate...just here to help :)

Comment: No Problem Shaz :)
I have provided more detail where i am registering anonymous method for the RadioButton.

Comment: @KamranShahid i belive you. you have provided more code but still i don't know is my answer is good for you. am i right when i said "you have an anonymous delegate method and you want to call it from a different location then just the event" cus if so then my answer is valid

Comment: I obviously wanted the logic registered in the anonymous delegate method to be called. As I mentioned the parameters and objects called into the anonymous delegate method are initialized prior.How can i passed it into the method and call it.
Kindly give the example considering my method

Comment: @KamranShahid i've edited the answer, let me know if it's better now

Comment: I can also move the logic into the method.But method instead 
SharedLogic(sender, e); my method will become 
SharedLogic(DocumentSimpleFieldDetailDto obj, Table table, Panel pnl, List<FieldDependency> objDependencyList)

as i needed the paremeter in those method

so i can't provide object sender, EventHandler e in the parameter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34687/discussion-between-no-idea-for-name-and-kamran-shahid)

Answer (score 0):

There are different way of using it..

```
public class NumberEventArgs : EventArgs
{
   private int _number;
   public NumberEventArgs(int num)
   {
      this._number = num;
   }
    public int getNumber
    {
      get
      {
        return _reached;
      }
}
// eventhandler Method
private void ShowMessage(object sender, NumberEventArgs e)
{
 MessageBox.Show("Hello user your ticket no is:" + e.getNumber().ToString());
}

 myRadioButton.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) =>{ ShowMessage(); }
 myRadioButton.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => MessageBox.Show(string.Format("sender is: {0} and eventargumnet is:{1}",sender.getType(),e.toString()};
 myRadioButton.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => string.Format("string = {0} and {1}", sender.getType() , e);
```

Comment: when people downvote you and don't leave a comment it suggest reputation hunter

Comment: +1 to counter your -1 and because it's a good qnswer, if you be so kind and if you think my answer is good to counter my -1

Comment: I have edited my questiona bit.I can't use the method as in the anonymous method i am using some paremeter and collection which i have used before registering the method